# What does 翻了个儿 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word

In the following sentence:

> 可毒瘾一发作，他就不停地流眼泪，流口水，哈欠连天就，接着便浑身冒冷汗，颤抖，肌肉疼，骨头疼，心呀、肝呀、肺呀什么的，全都**翻了个儿**，真是求生不得，求死无门。

In this sentence, what does 全都翻了个儿 mean? The words before that all mean the bad deseaces caused by drugs, so 全都 mean all of these symptons. But then what does 翻了个儿 mean?

In my understanding, 翻 here means "turn over" something like that, not "translate" or "double" I think. But then what does the 个儿 mean? 了 is the completion partice, right?

Comment: "everything has been turned upside down", " a lot of disorder has been caused" 翻个儿 see e.g. bkrs coll.
1) turn upside down or inside out
2) roll/turn over
3) turn over a new leaf; make a fresh start
loop the loop

Comment: So does that mean all of those symptoms keep bothering the person?

Comment: sounds like a reasonable conclusion, maybe stated health problems cause a feeling of the world turned on its head

Comment: don't do drugs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 可毒瘾一发作，他就不停地流眼泪，流口水，哈欠连天就，接着便浑身冒冷汗，颤抖，肌肉疼，骨头疼，{**心呀、肝呀、肺呀什么的，全都翻了个儿**}，真是求生不得，求死无门。

1. 全都 refers to 心呀、肝呀、肺呀什么的, **not all the symptoms**.
2. [翻个](https://wapbaike.baidu.com/item/%E7%BF%BB%E4%B8%AA/4381316?fr=aladdin), *turn over*, defined in baidu baike:

> 翻个
>
> fān gè
>
> 翻过来；颠倒过来：场上晒的麦子该～了。

3. 了, in 翻了个儿, denotes a completion, as you know. 儿 is erhua.

Answer (score 1):

翻个儿：(动)翻过来，overturn 颠倒过来 invert

烙馅儿饼要勤翻个儿 baking xianbing, you need to turn them constantly

可毒瘾一发作，
When his drug addiction flares up,
他就不停地流眼泪，
he can't stop crying,
流口水，
drooling,
哈欠连天就，
yawning,
接着便浑身冒冷汗，
followed then by a cold sweat all over his body,
颤抖，
shudders,
肌肉疼，
muscle ache,
骨头疼，
joint pains
心呀、肝呀、肺呀什么的，
heart, liver, lungs whatever,
全都翻了个儿，
everything is churning,
真是求生不得，求死无门。
really， (he) doesn't want to live, doesn't know how to die.